# "tkinter.TclError: invalid command name" error after calling root.destroy()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am in the process of learning tkinter on Python 3.X. I am writing a simple program which will get one or more balls (tkinter ovals) bouncing round a rectangular court (tkinter root window with a canvas and rectangle drawn on it).

I want to be able to terminate the program cleanly by pressing the `q` key, and have managed to bind the key to the root and fire the callback function when a key is pressed, which then calls `root.destroy()`.

However, I'm *still* getting errors of the form `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".140625086752360"` when I do so. This is driving me crazy. What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import numpy

class Ball:

    def bates():
        """
        Generator for the sequential index number used in order to 
        identify the various balls.
        """
        k = 0
        while True:
            yield k
            k += 1

    index = bates()

    def __init__(self, parent, x, y, v=0.0, angle=0.0, accel=0.0, radius=10, border=2):
        self.parent   = parent           # The parent Canvas widget
        self.index    = next(Ball.index) # Fortunately, I have all my feathers individually numbered, for just such an eventuality
        self.x        = x                # X-coordinate (-1.0 .. 1.0)
        self.y        = y                # Y-coordinate (-1.0 .. 1.0)
        self.radius   = radius           # Radius (0.0 .. 1.0)
        self.v        = v                # Velocity
        self.theta    = angle            # Angle
        self.accel    = accel            # Acceleration per tick
        self.border   = border           # Border thickness (integer)

        self.widget   = self.parent.canvas.create_oval(
                    self.px() - self.pr(), self.py() - self.pr(), 
                    self.px() + self.pr(), self.py() + self.pr(),
                    fill = "red", width=self.border, outline="black")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[{}] x={:.4f} y={:.4f} v={:.4f} a={:.4f} r={:.4f} t={}, px={} py={} pr={}".format(
                self.index, self.x, self.y, self.v, self.theta, 
                self.radius, self.border, self.px(), self.py(), self.pr())

    def pr(self):
        """
        Converts a radius from the range 0.0 .. 1.0 to window coordinates
        based on the width and height of the window
        """
        assert self.radius > 0.0 and self.radius <= 1.0
        return int(min(self.parent.height, self.parent.width)*self.radius/2.0)

    def px(self):
        """
        Converts an X-coordinate in the range -1.0 .. +1.0 to a position
        within the window based on its width
        """
        assert self.x >= -1.0 and self.x <= 1.0
        return int((1.0 + self.x) * self.parent.width / 2.0 + self.parent.border)

    def py(self):
        """
        Converts a Y-coordinate in the range -1.0 .. +1.0 to a position
        within the window based on its height
        """
        assert self.y >= -1.0 and self.y <= 1.0
        return int((1.0 - self.y) * self.parent.height / 2.0 + self.parent.border)

    def Move(self, x, y):
        """
        Moves ball to absolute position (x, y) where x and y are both -1.0 .. 1.0
        """
        oldx = self.px()
        oldy = self.py()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        deltax = self.px() - oldx
        deltay = self.py() - oldy
        if oldx != 0 or oldy != 0:
            self.parent.canvas.move(self.widget, deltax, deltay)

    def HandleWallCollision(self):
        """
        Detects if a ball collides with the wall of the rectangular
        Court.
        """
        pass

class Court:
    """
    A 2D rectangular enclosure containing a centred, rectagular
    grid of balls (instances of the Ball class).
    """    

    def __init__(self, 
                 width=1000,      # Width of the canvas in pixels
                 height=750,      # Height of the canvas in pixels
                 border=5,        # Width of the border around the canvas in pixels
                 rows=1,          # Number of rows of balls
                 cols=1,          # Number of columns of balls
                 radius=0.05,     # Ball radius
                 ballborder=1,    # Width of the border around the balls in pixels
                 cycles=1000,     # Number of animation cycles
                 tick=0.01):      # Animation tick length (sec)
        self.root = Tk()
        self.height = height
        self.width  = width
        self.border = border
        self.cycles = cycles
        self.tick   = tick
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=width+2*border, height=height+2*border)
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(border, border, width+border, height+border,                                      outline="black", fill="white", width=border)
        self.root.bind('<Key>', self.key)
        self.CreateGrid(rows, cols, radius, ballborder)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.afterid = self.root.after(0, self.Animate)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def __repr__(self):
        s = "width={} height={} border={} balls={}\n".format(self.width, 
                self.height, 
                self.border, 
                len(self.balls))
        for b in self.balls:
            s += "> {}\n".format(b)
        return s

    def key(self, event):
        print("Got key '{}'".format(event.char))
        if event.char == 'q':
            print("Bye!")
            self.root.after_cancel(self.afterid)
            self.root.destroy()

    def CreateGrid(self, rows, cols, radius, border):
        """
        Creates a rectangular rows x cols grid of balls of
        the specified radius and border thickness
        """
        self.balls = []
        for r in range(1, rows+1):
            y = 1.0-2.0*r/(rows+1)
            for c in range(1, cols+1):
                x = 2.0*c/(cols+1) - 1.0
                self.balls.append(Ball(self, x, y, 0.001, 
                                       numpy.pi/6.0, 0.0, radius, border))

    def Animate(self):
        """
        Animates the movement of the various balls
        """
        for c in range(self.cycles):
            for b in self.balls:
                b.v += b.accel
                b.Move(b.x + b.v * numpy.cos(b.theta), 
                       b.y + b.v * numpy.sin(b.theta))
            self.canvas.update()
            time.sleep(self.tick)
        self.root.destroy()
```

I've included the full listing for completeness, but I'm fairly sure that the problem lies in the `Court` class. I presume it's some sort of callback or similar firing but I seem to be beating my head against a wall trying to fix it.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. The answer suggested as a duplicate leaves after events running. This is slightly different in that the after events are closed but we have effectively two mainloops as the `Animate` function is miswritten to be a mainloop equivalent. The correct fix here is to change the Animate function to call itself using `after` after moving the balls. You should never be using `time.sleep` in a Tkinter program. That's what after is for.

Comment: Have you tried with 'try' statement to see if it works properly? (Debugging purposes only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have effectively got two mainloops. In your `Court.__init__` method you use `after` to start the `Animate` method and then start the Tk mainloop which will process events until you destroy the main Tk window.

However the `Animate` method basically replicates this mainloop by calling `update` to process events then `time.sleep` to waste some time and repeating this. When you handle the keypress and terminate your window, the Animate method is still running and attempts to update the canvas which no longer exists.

The correct way to handle this is to rewrite the `Animate` method to perform a single round of moving the balls and then schedule another call of `Animate` using `after` and provide the necessary delay as the `after` parameter. This way the event system will call your animation function at the correct intervals while still processing all other window system events promptly.